# Creating custom-session identifier by comparing records before and after

Tags: mysql, sql-server, teradata, amazon-redshift, vertica

I'm trying to create some session based on data ( In Vertica but any other OLAP database SQL should work )

I have a simple table, with columns named Vehicle-ID, Event, Event-Code, and "Session-ID" is the column which I want to  populate

I have tried partition, lead, lag and other analytics function but no luck. The logic for creating is session as below.

Session starts when you first encounter a started-event  ( 1 ) and ends when the last stopped(2) event is obtained. As you can see in session after a session is started if we get more start events we ignore and we look for last stop event. Example Session-Id-1

For some reason after stop event,  the next event is not start ( i.e running, etc ) it means it a bad session and we want to capture the bad session until we find a new-start. The example is in session-id-2

I'm trying to create markers use lead, and lag which look at records before and after , and adds markers like first_start, final_end etc .. but it's getting clumsy

Updated SQL Query to create session

```
SELECT * , SUM(FLAG) OVER ( PARTITION BY Vehicle_ID ORDER BY Event_Time ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS SESSION_ID
FROM (
    SELECT * ,
    Case when Prev_Start_time < Prev_Stop_time and Event != 'Started' Then 1 else 0 end as bad_data ,
    Case when 
        ( Event = 'Started' and Prev_Start_time < Prev_Stop_time ) OR 
        --( Event = 'Stopped' and Prev_Event = 'Stopped' ) OR 
        ( Event = 'Running' and Prev_Start_time < Prev_Stop_time) OR 
        ( Prev_Event IS NULL) 
    THEN 1 END AS FLAG
    --Case when ( Event = 'Stopped' and Next_Event = 'Stopped' ) OR ( Event != 'Started' and Prev_Start_time < Prev_Stop_time) OR ( Prev_Event IS NULL) THEN 1 END AS FLAG
    FROM (
    WITH
        input(Vehicle_ID,Event_time,Event,Event_Code) AS (
                  SELECT 1,TIME '09:01:00','Started',1
        UNION ALL SELECT 1,TIME '09:02:00','Started',1
        UNION ALL SELECT 1,TIME '09:03:00','Running',3
        UNION ALL SELECT 1,TIME '09:04:00','Started',1
        UNION ALL SELECT 1,TIME '09:05:00','Running',3
        UNION ALL SELECT 1,TIME '09:06:00','Running',3
        UNION ALL SELECT 1,TIME '09:07:00','Running',3
        UNION ALL SELECT 1,TIME '09:08:00','Stopped',2
        UNION ALL SELECT 1,TIME '09:09:00','Stopped',2
        UNION ALL SELECT 1,TIME '09:10:00','Running',3
        UNION ALL SELECT 1,TIME '09:11:00','Running',3
        UNION ALL SELECT 1,TIME '09:12:00','Running',3
        UNION ALL SELECT 1,TIME '09:13:00','Started',1
        UNION ALL SELECT 1,TIME '09:14:00','Started',1
        UNION ALL SELECT 1,TIME '09:15:00','Running',3
        UNION ALL SELECT 1,TIME '09:16:00','Started',1
        UNION ALL SELECT 1,TIME '09:17:00','Running',3
        UNION ALL SELECT 1,TIME '09:18:00','Running',3
        UNION ALL SELECT 1,TIME '09:19:00','Running',3
        UNION ALL SELECT 1,TIME '09:20:00','Stopped',2
        UNION ALL SELECT 1,TIME '09:21:00','Started',1
        UNION ALL SELECT 1,TIME '09:22:00','Started',1
        UNION ALL SELECT 1,TIME '09:23:00','Running',3
        UNION ALL SELECT 1,TIME '09:24:00','Started',1
        UNION ALL SELECT 1,TIME '09:25:00','Running',3
        UNION ALL SELECT 1,TIME '09:26:00','Running',3
        UNION ALL SELECT 1,TIME '09:27:00','Running',3
        UNION ALL SELECT 1,TIME '09:28:00','Stopped',2
        )
    SELECT *, 
    Max( Case Event when 'Started' then Event_time end ) OVER (PARTITION BY Vehicle_ID ORDER BY Event_time Rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding ) AS Prev_Start_time,
    Max( Case Event when 'Stopped' then Event_time end ) OVER (PARTITION BY Vehicle_ID ORDER BY Event_time Rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding ) AS Prev_Stop_time,
    LAG(Event) OVER (PARTITION BY Vehicle_ID ORDER BY Event_time ) AS Prev_Event,
    LEAD(Event) OVER (PARTITION BY Vehicle_ID ORDER BY Event_time ) AS Next_Event
    FROM input ) AS T1
) AS T2
```

New input as per the updated query

```
Vehicle_ID  Event_time      Event       Event_Code  Prev_Start_time Prev_Stop_time      Prev_Event      Next_Event      bad_data    FLAG        SESSION_ID
1           9:01:00         Started         1           NULL            NULL            NULL            Started         0           1           1
1           9:02:00         Started         1           9:01:00         NULL            Started         Running         0           NULL            1
1           9:03:00         Running         3           9:02:00         NULL            Started         Started         0           NULL            1
1           9:04:00         Started         1           9:02:00         NULL            Running         Running         0           NULL            1
1           9:05:00         Running         3           9:04:00         NULL            Started         Running         0           NULL            1
1           9:06:00         Running         3           9:04:00         NULL            Running         Running         0           NULL            1
1           9:07:00         Running         3           9:04:00         NULL            Running         Stopped         0           NULL            1
1           9:08:00         Stopped         2           9:04:00         NULL            Running         Stopped         0           NULL            1
1           9:09:00         Stopped         2           9:04:00         9:08:00         Stopped         Running         1           NULL            1
1           9:10:00         Running         3           9:04:00         9:09:00         Stopped         Running         1           1           2
1           9:11:00         Running         3           9:04:00         9:09:00         Running         Running         1           1           3
1           9:12:00         Running         3           9:04:00         9:09:00         Running         Started         1           1           4
1           9:13:00         Started         1           9:04:00         9:09:00         Running         Started         0           1           5
1           9:14:00         Started         1           9:13:00         9:09:00         Started         Running         0           NULL            5
1           9:15:00         Running         3           9:14:00         9:09:00         Started         Started         0           NULL            5
1           9:16:00         Started         1           9:14:00         9:09:00         Running         Running         0           NULL            5
1           9:17:00         Running         3           9:16:00         9:09:00         Started         Running         0           NULL            5
1           9:18:00         Running         3           9:16:00         9:09:00         Running         Running         0           NULL            5
1           9:19:00         Running         3           9:16:00         9:09:00         Running         Stopped         0           NULL            5
1           9:20:00         Stopped         2           9:16:00         9:09:00         Running         Started         0           NULL            5
1           9:21:00         Started         1           9:16:00         9:20:00         Stopped         Started         0           1           6
1           9:22:00         Started         1           9:21:00         9:20:00         Started         Running         0           NULL            6
1           9:23:00         Running         3           9:22:00         9:20:00         Started         Started         0           NULL            6
1           9:24:00         Started         1           9:22:00         9:20:00         Running         Running         0           NULL            6
1           9:25:00         Running         3           9:24:00         9:20:00         Started         Running         0           NULL            6
1           9:26:00         Running         3           9:24:00         9:20:00         Running         Running         0           NULL            6
1           9:27:00         Running         3           9:24:00         9:20:00         Running         Stopped         0           NULL            6
1           9:28:00         Stopped         2           9:24:00         9:20:00         Running         NULL            0           NULL            6
```

Comment: It's impressive that you've got this running on 4 separate rdbmses.

Comment: What is the ordering of the records here? That's sort of super important to using window functions like lag() and lead().

Comment: Event_time is the sort order ... vehicle ordered by event_time

Comment: In Vertica try [`Match Clause`](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.0.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Statements/SELECT/MATCHClause.htm?Highlight=MATCH) where behavior is actions `START/RUNNING/STOP`

Comment: You didn't translate the `flag` calculation correctly, should be `CASE WHEN 
        ( Event <> 'Stopped' AND Prev_event = 'Stopped' ) OR 
        ( Event = 'Started' AND Prev_Start_time < Prev_Stop_time) OR 
        ( Prev_Event IS NULL) 
    THEN 1 END AS FLAG`

Comment: If I add this ( Event <> 'Stopped' AND Prev_event = 'Stopped' ) then the last  stop record will add a flag and have a new session is , so I removed it so that all-stops fall in one session

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following seems to match yur description, I assume there's a column (named *whatever*) to order your data uniquely (probably a timestamp).

This will result in two STAT-steps in Teradata:

```
SELECT dt.*
  ,Sum(flag) -- (cumulative sum or COUNT(*) to create the session id
   Over (PARTITION BY Vehicle_ID
         ORDER BY whatever
         ROWS Unbounded Preceding) AS session_id_
FROM
(
   SELECT mytable.* 

     -- previous start
     ,Max(CASE event_code WHEN 1 THEN whatever END) 
      Over (PARTITION BY Vehicle_ID
            ORDER BY whatever 
            ROWS BETWEEN Unbounded Preceding AND 1 Preceding) AS prev_start

     -- previous stop
     ,Max(CASE event_code WHEN 2 THEN whatever END) 
      Over (PARTITION BY Vehicle_ID
            ORDER BY whatever
            ROWS BETWEEN Unbounded Preceding AND 1 Preceding) AS prev_stop

     -- previous event
     ,Lag(event_code) 
      Over (PARTITION BY Vehicle_ID
            ORDER BY whatever) AS lag_event

     -- no new session started after previous stop and current event is not start = bad data
     ,CASE WHEN prev_start < prev_stop AND event_code <> 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS bad_data

                                                               -- new session starts at
     ,CASE WHEN   (event_code <> 2 AND (lag_event = 2) )       -- first row after a stop (ignore consecutive stops)
               OR (event_code =  1 AND prev_start < prev_stop) -- first row after bad data
               OR lag_event IS NULL                            -- first row
           THEN 1 
      END AS flag

   FROM mytable
) AS dt
```

For Oracle/SQL Server you need to add another nesting level to be able to use the aliases within the CASEs.

Comment: Forgot to add the sort order .. partition is vehicle over event_time

Comment: I had to go with your approach due to limitation of match clause. I'm able to get the desired result, along with the generated session_id, can I associate a UUID/GUID for a session ?

Comment: I can apply logic to see if prev_session id same as current if so copy the copy the GUID  else create a new guid. I wanted to see if there is anything we can sneak-in the above query instead of one more pass

Comment: @Manjesh: Where is the GUID coming from?

Comment: I have to create a GUID just to uniquely identify a session, since this query will be run on incremental when we insert back to fact table for a give vehicle we will have duplicate session_id for each run , so we want to have a column named as SESSION_GUID

Comment: The easiest way is `last_value(case when flag = 1 then newGUID end ignore nulls) Over (PARTITION BY Vehicle_ID order by event_time)`, but not all DBMSes support `ignore nulls`. In Teradata you will need a UDF to create the GUID. Or you add the current Unixtime to the session_id, to avoid duplicates you can either make a BIGINT `unixtime * 1000000 + session_id` or `cast(unixtime as decimal(18,8)) + session_id / 1000000`

Answer (score 3):

In Vertica, I'd use the MATCH() clause. It would also leave out the unwanted rows - the ones 'running' that make no sense.
try this:

```
    WITH
    -- your input as you gave it 
    input(tm,Vehicle_ID,Col1,Event,Event_Code,Session_ID) AS (
              SELECT TIME '09:01:00',1,'A','Started',1,1
    UNION ALL SELECT TIME '09:02:00',1,'B','Started',1,1
    UNION ALL SELECT TIME '09:03:00',1,'C','Running',3,1
    UNION ALL SELECT TIME '09:04:00',1,'A','Started',1,1
    UNION ALL SELECT TIME '09:05:00',1,'B','Running',3,1
    UNION ALL SELECT TIME '09:06:00',1,'C','Running',3,1
    UNION ALL SELECT TIME '09:07:00',1,'A','Running',3,1
    UNION ALL SELECT TIME '09:08:00',1,'A','Stopped',2,1
    UNION ALL SELECT TIME '09:09:00',1,'B','Stopped',2,1
    UNION ALL SELECT TIME '09:10:00',1,'C','Running',3,2
    UNION ALL SELECT TIME '09:11:00',1,'A','Running',3,2
    UNION ALL SELECT TIME '09:12:00',1,'B','Running',3,2
    UNION ALL SELECT TIME '09:13:00',1,'A','Started',1,3
    UNION ALL SELECT TIME '09:14:00',1,'B','Started',1,3
    UNION ALL SELECT TIME '09:15:00',1,'C','Running',3,3
    UNION ALL SELECT TIME '09:16:00',1,'A','Started',1,3
    UNION ALL SELECT TIME '09:17:00',1,'B','Running',3,3
    UNION ALL SELECT TIME '09:18:00',1,'C','Running',3,3
    UNION ALL SELECT TIME '09:19:00',1,'A','Running',3,3
    UNION ALL SELECT TIME '09:20:00',1,'A','Stopped',2,3
    )
    -- here is where the real select starts ..
    SELECT
      pattern_id()
    , match_id()
    , event_name()
    , *
    FROM input
    MATCH(
      PARTITION BY vehicle_id
      ORDER BY tm
      DEFINE
        started_event AS (event='Started')
      , running_event AS (event='Running')
      , stopped_event AS (event='Stopped')
      PATTERN p AS (started_event+ (running_event|started_event)* stopped_event+)
    )
    ;


    pattern_id|match_id|event_name   |tm      |Vehicle_ID|Col1|Event  |Event_Code|Session_ID
             1|       1|started_event|09:01:00|         1|A   |Started|         1|         1
             1|       2|started_event|09:02:00|         1|B   |Started|         1|         1
             1|       3|running_event|09:03:00|         1|C   |Running|         3|         1
             1|       4|started_event|09:04:00|         1|A   |Started|         1|         1
             1|       5|running_event|09:05:00|         1|B   |Running|         3|         1
             1|       6|running_event|09:06:00|         1|C   |Running|         3|         1
             1|       7|running_event|09:07:00|         1|A   |Running|         3|         1
             1|       8|stopped_event|09:08:00|         1|A   |Stopped|         2|         1
             1|       9|stopped_event|09:09:00|         1|B   |Stopped|         2|         1
             2|       1|started_event|09:13:00|         1|A   |Started|         1|         3
             2|       2|started_event|09:14:00|         1|B   |Started|         1|         3
             2|       3|running_event|09:15:00|         1|C   |Running|         3|         3
             2|       4|started_event|09:16:00|         1|A   |Started|         1|         3
             2|       5|running_event|09:17:00|         1|B   |Running|         3|         3
             2|       6|running_event|09:18:00|         1|C   |Running|         3|         3
             2|       7|running_event|09:19:00|         1|A   |Running|         3|         3
```

Comment: (Well, the input is yours, plus one column marking the time, which is needed, as dnoeth pointed out).

Comment: Since the output of above query make in to FACT table we cannot afford to have missing records. Is there way to get 09:10,09:11,09:12 as a session as well. I tried some permutation with ? , * , + but could not get the above 3 in to separate session https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.0.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Statements/SELECT/MATCHClause.htm

Comment: Put the output of the MATCH() clause query into a temp table, and LEFT JOIN the temp table with the original input.